# Android image drawable folder issue

Tags: android, android-layout

in my android application I've the same image in both the `drawable` folder and `drawable-hdpi` with different names (svs.jpg and svs1.jpg)

First, I've used svs.jpg (drawable folder)

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/svs"
 />
```

In one system it runs without any hindrance, but it shows error in another system (`Inflate exception error` in binary xml file). So I've used the image svs1.jpg as `android:background="@drawable/svs1"`. Now it is working..

If I use svs1.jpg on the first system it shows error. I don't understand this problem. Can someone say why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Images in different resource folders are meant to get the same name so the device will choose the one to use.

If they don't, I suppose some device are looking for the image name in the 'drawable' and crash if they don't find it, other device will look in the 'device-hdpi' folder and crash if they don't find it.

more information on [supporting multiple screen here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: You mean, if I use 10 images, I have to copy all the 10 images into all of these drawable, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi folders?

Comment: for different screen resolutions you need to provide different drawables

Comment: yep, 10 images => make them with 3 different qualities. You end up with 30 drawables in your app but it will fit any screen size. This is the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are really misunderstanding what these folders do.
Your android will select folder based on it's **screen size** or **pixel-density** of device on which u run it

If Your device has a medium Pixel density and a large screen. So it selects its resources from the res folders with those given qualifiers.

```
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
```

and images from

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png
```

You cannot tell your device to get images from the hdpi folder because it does not have a high pixel density.

So u give name of image same in all drawable folders .. Your device by default ll decide from which folder to take image , you need not worry about tat.

and just make sure the right images are in the right folders.